# JQuery Nestable with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-nestable

I'm currently using JQuery Nestable plug-in in my application to create nested list. Each item on the list contains a checkbox.

```js
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('.dd').nestable({
        collapsedClass: 'dd-collapsed'
      }).nestable('collapseAll');
      //$('.dd-handle a').on('mousedown', function (e) {
      //    e.stopPropagation();
      //});
      $(".dd-nodrag").on("mousedown", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
      $(".dd-nodrag").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="dd shadowed">
  <ol class="dd-list">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ModulesList) {
    <li class="dd-item bordered-inverse">
      <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input name="selectedModules" class="colored-blue" id="selectedModules" type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" checked="@item.Selected" disabled="@item.Disabled">
            <span class="text">@item.Name</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      @if (@item.items.Count > 0) {
      <ol class="dd-list">
        @foreach (var sub in @item.items) {
        <li class="dd-item bordered-blue">
          <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input name="selectedsubModules" class="colored-blue" id="selectedsubModules" type="checkbox" value="@sub.Id" checked="@sub.Selected">
                <span class="text">@sub.Name</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        }
      </ol>
      }
    </li>
    }
  </ol>
</div>
```

the list is generated properly, however, the checkboxes are not clickable.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

HTML SOURCE:

```
<div class="dd shadowed">
                            <ol class="dd-list">
                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-inverse">
                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
                                                    <span class="text">Home</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-inverse">
                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="2">
                                                    <span class="text">Pipeline</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <ol class="dd-list">
                                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-blue">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="1">
                                                                    <span class="text">Deal</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-blue">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="2">
                                                                    <span class="text">Setting</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ol>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-inverse">
                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
                                                    <span class="text">Profile</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-inverse">
                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="4" checked="checked">
                                                    <span class="text">Admin</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <ol class="dd-list">
                                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-blue">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked">
                                                                    <span class="text">User</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-blue">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="4" checked="checked">
                                                                    <span class="text">Role</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-blue">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="5" checked="checked">
                                                                    <span class="text">Group</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="dd-item bordered-blue">
                                                        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input class="colored-blue" type="checkbox" value="6" checked="checked">
                                                                    <span class="text">Module</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ol>
                                    </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have disabled all your checkboxes! (added the `disabled` attribute). And you have invalid html due to duplicate `id` attributes

Comment: some of the checkboxes are disabled depending on the value of @item.Selected. what duplicate id attributes?

Comment: Every checkbox has `id="selectedModules` and every checkbox in the outer loop is disabled (`disabled="disabled"` or `disabled="false"` or `disabled="anyValueAtAll"` all make the checkbox disabled). And every checkbox will also be checked.

Comment: None of that is the issue. Only 2 of the check boxes are disabled and that is what I want. see html source above.

Comment: It does not matter what the value of `item.Selected` is, the checkbox will be disabled. If you want then disabled, then just use `disabled="disabled"`. But you cannot select disabled checkboxes so what is your question? If your referring to the checkboxes in the inner loop which are not disabled, they are checkable - (run the 'Code Snippet' under you code). If they are not in your view, then its due to an issue you have not shown us

Comment: Stephen, it has nothing to do with item.Selected, I using that in several places, and it works just fine. this problem is only happening when I use the Nestable plug-in.

Comment: You have invalid html with duplicate `id` attributes. You are giving your disabled checkboxes both `name` and `value` attributes which is pointless since they don't post back. Your use of `disabled="@item.Disabled"` meas no matter what the value of `item.Disabled` is, it will always be disabled. Ditto for `checked="@sub.Selected"`. Nothing in your code makes sense.

Comment: All your checkboxes are inside `<div class="dd-nodrag">` and you have scripts that cancel both the `mousedown` and `click` events. Remove the scripts and they will be selectable

Comment: The is the problem, removing that fix it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen, 
I changed this:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.dd').nestable({
            collapsedClass: 'dd-collapsed'
        }).nestable('collapseAll');
        $('.dd-handle a').on('mousedown', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(".dd-nodrag").on("mousedown", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        $(".dd-nodrag").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

TO:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.dd').nestable({
            collapsedClass: 'dd-collapsed'
        }).nestable('collapseAll');
    });
```

Works fine now.